# Vsphere VMware thin provisioning free space

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-vsphere

All the VMs that I have created have thin provisioning enabled. I need to create a new VM for upgrade process. Two VMs will be turned off prior to the upgrade and deleted after the upgrade. My question is when creating the new VMs, if I do have thin provisioning enabled, would it be sufficient if my VM Space goes to 50 GB. Then after the upgrade the old VMs will be deleted as a result freeing up space.

Comment: I think we are going to need a lot more details about what steps you'll be taking and what kind of upgrade you are doing before a good solid answer can be given.

Comment: Basically creating new VMS with minimum required space. backing up the databases on the day of the upgrade. Running the upgrade and then once it is complete, deleting the old VMs. I don't know if that's sufficient enough.

Answer (score 2):

This entirely depends on the expected growth of your other VM's on the datastore.

You can run VM's with 0kb free - writes will just fail (by "run" I mean "have powered on" - they probably won't be doing much). So as long as you are confident that your other VMs are not going to grow by more than 50Gb in that time, then go for it.

And if your other VMs *are* going to use that last 50Gb in the time it takes you to get the other servers online, you're probably going to have bigger trouble even after you delete the other VMs as you'll probably be out of disk space soon anyway.